# Use Xcode UIAutomation to record user interactions on ios apps when connected to Mac system

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, appium

I have gone across Appium and recorded the user interactions in iOS Apps with the help of Appium . My aim is to replicate the same feature of recording user interaction and saving the recorded actions into some specific directory in Mac system and later utilize the same whenever required . Is there any way to do that if so can anyone guide me ? . I will be using iOS app signed with developer profile .

Answer (score 0):

This might be too obvious but, have you looked at Apple's documentation? You can definitely record user interactions on UIA and then save the script for later use.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html